# when calculating diameter of a tree why calculating height alone is not sufficient

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree

In finding the diameter of the tree we look into the maximum of the following:

1: diameter of left sub tree

2: diameter of right sub tree

3: height of left sub tree  + height of right sub tree + 1.

why these three is necessary? why 3. alone is not sufficient. lets take a simple eg of 3 node tree and 2 node tree. In the former 3rd point alone gives 1 + 1 + 1 = 3. 
while in latter case 3rd point alone gives 0 + 1 + 1 = 2.

In such case why we need to find the max of three. Plz explain

Comment: What do you mean by "*diameter*"?

Comment: The diameter of a tree (sometimes called the width) is the number of nodes on the longest path between two leaves in the tree                                     http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following tree:

```
         [A]
        /
      [B]
     /   \
  [C]     [D]
  /         \
[E]         [F]
```

The height of the left subtree of `A` is 3; the height of the right subtree of `A` is 0. Therefore condition 3 gives us 3 + 0 + 1 = 4.

But the diameter of the tree is 5: The nodes on the path between `E` and `F` are `E`, `C`, `B`, `D`, `F`.

As [the page you linked to](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) explains, condition 3 only applies to paths that go through the root of the tree. If the longest path between two leaves does not go through the root, it falls under condition 1 or 2. The first diagram on that page even shows an example:

[image: tree diagram]

The right tree has a diameter of 9, but condition 3 gives only 5 + 2 + 1 = 8.